# Asynchronous FIFO Design

Tags: verilog, fifo

I found the following piece of code in the internet , while searching for good FIFO design. From the link[SVN Code FIFO -Author Clifford E. Cummings](http://subversion.assembla.com/svn/ecpe-293-b/trunk/netfpga/lib/verilog/core/utils/src/small_async_fifo.v) . I did some research , I was not able to figure out why there are three pointers in the design ?I can read the code but what am I missing ?

```
 module sync_r2w #(parameter ADDRSIZE = 4)
 (output reg [ADDRSIZE:0] wq2_rptr,
 input [ADDRSIZE:0] rptr,
 input wclk, wrst_n);
 reg [ADDRSIZE:0] wq1_rptr;
 always @(posedge wclk or negedge wrst_n)
 if (!wrst_n) {wq2_rptr,wq1_rptr} <= 0;
 else {wq2_rptr,wq1_rptr} <= {wq1_rptr,rptr};
endmodule


module sync_w2r #(parameter ADDRSIZE = 4)
 (output reg [ADDRSIZE:0] rq2_wptr,
 input [ADDRSIZE:0] wptr,
 input rclk, rrst_n);
 reg [ADDRSIZE:0] rq1_wptr;
 always @(posedge rclk or negedge rrst_n)
 if (!rrst_n) {rq2_wptr,rq1_wptr} <= 0;
 else {rq2_wptr,rq1_wptr} <= {rq1_wptr,wptr};
endmodule
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you are looking at here is what's called a dual rank synchronizer.  As you mentioned this is an asynchronous FIFO.  This means that the read and write sides of the FIFO are not on the same clock domain.

As you know flip-flops need to have setup and hold timing requirements met in order to function properly.  When you drive a signal from one clock domain to the other there is no way to guarantee this requirements in the general case.

When you violate these requirements FFs go into what is called a 'meta-stable' state where there are indeterminate for a small time and then (more or less) randomly go to 1 or 0.  They do this though (and this is important) in much less than one clock cycle.

That's why the two layers of flops here.  The first has a chance of going meta-stable but should resolve in time to be captured cleanly by the 2nd set of flops.

This on it's own is not enough to pass a multi-bit value (the address pointer) across clock domains.  If more than one bit is changing at the same time then you can't be sure that the transition will be clean on the other side.  So what you'll see often in these situations is that the FIFO pointers will by gray coded.  This means that each increment of the counter changes at most one bit at a time.

e.g. Rather than 00 -> 01 -> 10 -> 11 -> 00 ...  it will be 00 -> 01 -> 11 -> 10 -> 00 ...

Clock domain crossing is a deep and subtle subject.  Even experienced designers very often mess them up without careful thought.

BTW ordinary Verilog simulations will not show anything about what I just described in a zero-delay sim.  You need to do back annotated SDF simulations with real timing models.

Answer (score 2):

In this example, the address is passed through the [shift register](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_register) in order for it to be delayed by one clock cycle. There could have been more “pointers” in order to delay the output even more.

Generally, it is easier to understand what is going on and why if you simulate the design and look at the waveform.

Also, here are some good FIFO implementations you can look at:

1. [Xilinx FIFO Generator IP Core](http://www.xilinx.com/products/intellectual-property/FIFO_Generator.htm)
2. [Altera's single/double-clock FIFOs](http://www.altera.com/literature/ug/ug_fifo.pdf)
3. [OpenCores Generic FIFOs](http://opencores.org/project,generic_fifos)

Hope it helps. Good Luck!